# Blurry text in text boxes (IE)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Sometimes (but not always) we get textboxes that looks like this, the text is sort of doubled.

[image: example of problem]

The problem only seems to appear in IE (of course). Anyone know what is causing this effect?

Here is the computed css from Chrome's 12 tools:

```
border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: block;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 18px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 4px;
padding-top: 3px;
position: absolute;
text-align: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 57px;
zoom: 1;
```

And the markup for the element:

```html
 <div class="t-widget t-numerictextbox">
     <div class="t-formatted-value" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: start; text-decoration: none; text-transform: none; display: block;">
      4&nbsp;510&nbsp;000
     </div>
     <input class="t-input" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Årsomsättning must be a number." data-val-required="The Årsomsättning field is required." id="AvtalsArbetslag[6bb6b024-d3db-4073-a0c4-0e774f028509]_Arsomsattning" name="AvtalsArbetslag[6bb6b024-d3db-4073-a0c4-0e774f028509].Arsomsattning" style="width: 80px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="text" value="4510000">
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the html and css?

Comment: I've added the css and html

Comment: Try to make the value of 'zoom: 0' ...and let me iif it helps...ok

Comment: Are you using IE quirks mode? Try to use Standard mode